# Escaped for JSON nested nodes using union command

Tags: json, sql-server, escaping, union, sql-server-2017

In a stored procedure I have a `for json` node (boxes):

```
select
(
    select
        os.Name,
        os.Address,
        ss.carrierCode,
        (
            select 
                ob.envelopeCode, 
                ob.boxNumber,
                ob.weight,
                ob.width,
                ob.length,
                ob.height  
            from OrdersBoxes ob
            ...
            where os.OID=ob.OID 
            ...
            for json path 
        ) boxes,
        ....
        for json path
) orderDetails
```

In this way I correctly get:

```
"boxes":[{
            "envelopeCode":"E70345D2AB90A879D4F53506FB465086",
            "boxNumber":1,
            "weight":3000,
            "width":300,
            "length":300,
            "height":100
        }]
```

Now I need to get details from 2 tables, therefore I will use `union` command, wrap the 2 `select` in another `select` the query to avoid following error:

> The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table or common table expression or view and apply FOR XML or FOR JSON on top of it.

And add `JSON_QUERY` to avoid to get escaped nested node:

```
select
(
    select 
        * 
    from 
    (
        select
            os.Name,
            os.Address,
            ss.carrierCode,
            JSON_QUERY((
                select 
                    ob.envelopeCode, 
                    ob.boxNumber,
                    ob.weight,
                    ob.width,
                    ob.length,
                    ob.height  
                from OrdersBoxes ob
                ...
                where os.OID=ob.OID 
                ...
                for json path 
            )) boxes,
            ....
            from table1
            where....
        
        union
        
        select
            os.Name,
            os.Address,
            ss.carrierCode,
            JSON_QUERY((
                select 
                    ob.envelopeCode, 
                    ob.boxNumber,
                    ob.weight,
                    ob.width,
                    ob.length,
                    ob.height  
                from OrdersBoxes ob
                ...
                where os.OID=ob.OID 
                ...
                for json path 
            )) boxes,
            ....
            from table2
            where....
    ) jj
    for json path
) orderDetails
```

That works, but boxes node is returned escaped:

```
"boxes":"[{\"envelopeCode\":\"E70345D2AB90A879D4F53506FB465086\",\"boxNumber\":1,\"weight\":3000,\"width\":300,\"length\":300,\"height\":100}]"
```

I tried also this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653273/transact-sql-union-all-on-json-results-escaping-nested-json-queries) but it works well only if returning data from 1 table:

since it returns `objects` `{}` to get an array need to change first line from

```
select STRING_AGG (order_details,',') ods from (
```

to

```
select concat('[',STRING_AGG (order_details,','),']') ods from (
```

and it seems me not very "elegant" although it works.

Can someone suggest a better way to get all data correctly formatted (thus unescaped boxes node)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation about `JSON_QUERY()` [explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-json_query-with-for-json): *... JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value. If you're returning results with FOR JSON, and you're including data that's already in JSON format (in a column or as the result of an expression), wrap the JSON data with JSON_QUERY without the path parameter.*. So, if I understand the schema correctly, you need to use `JSON_QUERY()` differently:

Tables:

```
SELECT *
INTO table1
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'Name1', 'Address1')
) v (oid, name, address)
SELECT *
INTO table2
FROM (VALUES
   (2, 'Name2', 'Address2')
) v (oid, name, address)
SELECT *
INTO OrdersBoxes 
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'E70345D2AB90A879D4F53506FB465086', 1, 3000, 300, 300, 100),
   (2, 'e70345D2AB90A879D4F53506FB465086', 2, 3000, 300, 300, 100)
) v (oid, envelopeCode, boxNumber, weight, width, length, height)
```

Statement:

```
select Name, Address, JSON_QUERY(boxes) AS Boxes
from (
   select
      os.Name,
      os.Address,
      (
      select ob.envelopeCode, ob.boxNumber, ob.weight, ob.width, ob.length, ob.height  
      from OrdersBoxes ob
      where os.OID = ob.OID 
      for json path 
      ) boxes
   from table1 os
   union all
   select
      os.Name,
      os.Address,
      (
      select ob.envelopeCode, ob.boxNumber, ob.weight, ob.width, ob.length, ob.height   
      from OrdersBoxes ob
      where os.OID = ob.OID 
      for json path 
      ) boxes
   from table2 os
) j
for json path
```

As an additional option, you may try to use `FOR JSON AUTO` (the format of the JSON output is automatically determined based on the order of columns in the `SELECT` list and their source tables):

```
SELECT 
   cte.Name, cte.Address, 
   boxes.envelopeCode, boxes.boxNumber, boxes.weight, boxes.width, boxes.length, boxes.height
FROM (
   SELECT oid, name, address FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT oid, name, address FROM table2
) cte
JOIN OrdersBoxes boxes ON cte.oid = boxes.oid
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[
   {
   "Name":"Name1",
   "Address":"Address1",
   "boxes":[{"envelopeCode":"E70345D2AB90A879D4F53506FB465086","boxNumber":1,"weight":3000,"width":300,"length":300,"height":100}]
   },
   {
   "Name":"Name2",
   "Address":"Address2",
   "boxes":[{"envelopeCode":"e70345D2AB90A879D4F53506FB465086","boxNumber":2,"weight":3000,"width":300,"length":300,"height":100}]
   }
]
```

Comment: yess... thanks a lot... and Merry Christmas!